# Smooth transitions in Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge

I have a sidebar transition that works fine in Firefox, but the first time it is used, the animation is "jerky" in Edge. It lags and then comes out really fast in that browser. After the first time of use per-page-load, it behaves smoothly like in Firefox though. I know Edge has issues with translate all but even specifying the transition type (translatex) in the CSS code did nothing for me.

```js
var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
var burger = document.getElementById('BurgerID');

burger.addEventListener('click', function() {

      if (burger.classList.contains('open')) {
        burger.classList.remove('open');
          sidebar.style.transform = 'translateX(400%)';
      } else {
        burger.classList.add('open');
          sidebar.style.transform = 'translateX(300%)';
    sidebar.style.zIndex = 998;
      }

});
```

```css
sidebar {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.90);
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateX(400%);
    transition: all .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: translatex .5s ease;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="BurgerID" class="">
            <mark class="mark-1"></mark>
            <mark class="mark-2"></mark>
            <mark class="mark-3"></mark>
</div>
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
```

Comment: Edge is very outdated and yeah it has translation issues, it won't rely on having anything to do with your code. Do u import any external files? If you do then they will be slowing it down and causing it to jump around. If not, its just edge.

Comment: I try to check your code and find that your code has several missing things, It is even not showing the sidebar in any browser. I suggest you to post a working sample code that can produce the issue. Also try to inform us, Which version of MS Edge you are using currently? It may help us to check the issue with specific version of the Edge while testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell because your code sample doesn't run, but you could try adding `will-change: transform;` to your sidebar element.

> The will-change CSS property hints to browsers how an element is expected to change. Browsers may set up optimizations before an element is actually changed. These kinds of optimizations can increase the responsiveness of a page by doing potentially expensive work before they are actually required.
>
> **Important:** will-change is intended to be used as a last resort, in order to try to deal with existing performance problems. It should not be used to anticipate performance problems.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change